# SQL Server aggregate function without joining view to table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

My title is confusing, but I got no other way to describe it.

I have a view that gives me one row based on certain criteria. Using this view I want to filter another table which the records date must be equal or bigger than the value from the view. After that I need to sum all records of this table and subtract to a column in the view.

An example:

View

```
==========================
Item | Value | LastDate
==========================
 A      10     2017-02-01
 B      5      2017-02-03
 C      0      NULL
--------------------------
```

**Records** table:

```
==========================
Item | Value | Date
==========================
 A      20     2017-01-01
 A      -5     2017-02-04 
 A       5     2017-02-03 
 A      10     2017-02-04 
 B       5     2017-01-01 
 B       5     2017-02-21 
 B       5     2017-02-22 
 B      10     2017-02-23 
--------------------------
```

Desired result

```
=======================================
Item | Value | LastDate    | RecordsSum
=======================================
 A      10     2017-02-01     10
 B      5      2017-02-03     20
 C      0      NULL           NULL
---------------------------------------
```

I've tried to use [Fabiano's](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/window-functions-in-sql-server/) approach, however I get the records table data joined when I just want the sum.

I could use another view to calculate the value and join it to the first view after, however this approach would make two queries to the database, making it inefficient since it will run against >1000k records.

I know I might need to use a CTE, but I can't make it work.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Your output doesn't make any sense to me based on the sample data. Can you try to explain the logic of what you are trying to do?

Comment: RecordsSum for Item A should be 30?

Comment: Simply put. I need to sum value column from the records table, where date >= lastdate and Item = Item @SeanLange

Comment: @lamak Not if you figure the date restriction.

Comment: @JohnPasquet I could swear that the first row had `'2017-02-01'` as the date. Must have need more coffee

Comment: @Lamak, no because for item A, i can only sum after `2017-02-01` wich is the lastdate returned by the view

Comment: @Lamak Programming is, in fact, defined as the conversion of coffee into code.  :)

Answer (score 2):

How about something like this?

```
select v.Item
    , v.Value
    , v.LastDate
    , SUM(r.Value) as RecordsSum
from View v
join Record r on r.Item = v.Item
                and r.Date > v.LastDate
group by v.Item
    , v.Value
    , v.LastDate
```

Comment: My solution should work as well, but yours is probably more efficient.  +1

Answer (score 0):

It seems you just need one additional column attached to all the columns of your view:

```
SELECT Item, Value, [Date], 
    (SELECT SUM(Value)
     FROM MyTable
     WHERE MyTable.Item = MyView.Item
        AND MyTable.Date > MyView.Date) AS RecordsSum
FROM MyView
```

Comment: I could have used this approach but would'nt it make the query slow, considering the table dimension?

Comment: Depends on indexing, but yes, the other answer might be more efficient, as I stated in my comment.  That's why I made that comment on the other answer and upvoted that.